# mediagoblin can't create docker container - Invalid environment marker

Tags: docker

Following the instructions at https://notabug.org/dachary/mediagoblin-docker to create a MediaGoblin installation.

MediaGoblin runs fine in the `docker run dachary/mediagoblin` mode.

However the `docker build -t mediagoblin-demo mediagoblin-docker` stage with errors [like](https://pastebin.com/6kAGWuYW):

```
Setup script exited with error in Sphinx setup command: Invalid environment marker: python_version<"3.5"
Makefile:123: recipe for target 'bin/python' failed
make: *** [bin/python] Error 1
The command '/bin/sh -c cd /srv/mediagoblin.example.org/mediagoblin && sudo -u mediagoblin make' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Tried so far:

- Memory is only 2GB, but doesn't seem to be running out (peaks at 75% memory usage)
- Plenty of disk space
- Host is Linux Mint 18.2
- Error message says "Invalid environment marker: python_version<3.5" - although the host's version of python3 is 3.5.1-3
- All commands have `sudo` permission
- Got the latest git download from notabug.org
- setuptools (easy_install) is version 33.1.1

Any ideas?

Comment: https://mediagoblin.org/pages/join.html

Comment: question has been cross-posted to #mediagoblin@freenode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appears to be [/issue/6](https://notabug.org/dachary/mediagoblin-docker/issues/6) in the bugtracker.  A solution is described in [pull request 5](https://notabug.org/dachary/mediagoblin-docker/pulls/5/commits).

Adding python-sphinx to the `apt-get install` command near the top of the 'Dockerfile' script avoids this problem, and allows the docker container to be created.

Answer (score 0):

I created a [fork](https://github.com/mtlynch/mediagoblin-docker) that fixes the issue. You can build with the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/mtlynch/mediagoblin-docker.git
cd mediagoblin-docker
docker build --tag mediagoblin .
```